# FtpWebRequest.KeepAlive is not working

Tags: c#, .net, ftpwebrequest

I try to download more than one file with FtpWebRequest but with only one logging-in to the server. I use KeepAlive property (also with .ConnectionGroupName) but it doesn't work.

The code:

```
        List<string> downloaded = new List<string>();

        NetworkCredential networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(_ftpConfiguration.Username, _ftpConfiguration.Password);

        foreach (var dataId in requestDataIDs)
        {
            string uri = "ftp://" + _ftpConfiguration.Host + "//" + dataId;
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
            request.ConnectionGroupName = "myConnection";
            request.KeepAlive = true;
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
            request.Credentials = networkCredential;

            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
            downloaded.Add(reader.ReadToEnd());

            reader.Close();
            response.Close();
        }

        return downloaded;
```

The "QUIT" message is sent to the server after "reader.ReadToEnd()".
When I comment last three lines in the loop, there is no "QUIT" message, but also each request makes logging-in to the server.

I'd like to make it on .NET Core 2.0, but also have tried on .NET Framework 4.6.1 with the same effect.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I've checked your code with ftp://speedtest.tele2.net/ and it downloaded files without "QUIT" command.

Comment: How do you know that "QUIT" command was not sent? I tested code with FileZilla and saw the commands in FileZilla Server window live.

Comment: I used [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) packet analyzer.

Answer (score 2):

`KeepAlive` is not supported in .Net Core, yet. Per `2.1` it says:

> "We don't support connection pooling, so just silently ignore this."

[FtpWebRequest on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/943051ffe4d804af417d9b6915ce93a432850c3c/src/System.Net.Requests/src/System/Net/FtpWebRequest.cs#L1561)